# Camera tearing when using "Capture GPU frame" on iOS with OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es, camera

I'm on iOS 10.1 with Xcode 8.2.1

I use OpenGL ES 2.0 to render camera frames on screen.

The camera displayed correctly at runtime, but if I use "Capture GPU frame" button in Xcode, I get tearing in camera shots like that:

[image]

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you have the row stride wrong when you import the image into GL, so each row is slightly too short, which accumulates into the lovely diagonal patterns you are getting.

Comment: The pattern only appears when I use 'Capture GPU frame', the app itself looks fine.
You talking about `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`? Never seen any camera code examples to use it. I've tried setting both `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` and `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1`, but it didn't fix it.
PS: I use `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` to upload frame to the GPU, and it uploads with tearing.

Comment: Normally it's a combination of `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` and `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to get a stride to work in OpenGL ES.  

That said, I have no idea how this works internally in iOS. If it's importing the image via an EGL image then the application may get no control over the stride at all (as it's specified on the image import), in which case I think you're stuck.